# Vb.net Freezing column in 2 different datagridviews

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Googling this gave me only references to the scroll bars, but that is not my issue.

I have a Tab control on my form, it has 2 tabs. On each tab there is a datagridview. The data is retrieved from my database and bound to the datagrid. The two separate tabs hold slightly different data, but with mostly the same columns. I want to freeze the first two columns and I have the code for it and it works fine, except on the initial loading of the form. When the form is loaded for the first time it access the same information that I would get if I clicked the button to import the data into the datagrid. Except when it hits the function to freeze the columns in the first tab the column is frozen, but on the second one it basically dumps all data that was in the datagrid. Which doesn't make sense because the data is still there it just isn't showing when I click on the tab.

Anyone have any idea why it would do this? and how to fix it?

Believe me I have walked through it like 6 times and had someone here look at it and it doesn't make sense. But ok I guess I can put the code in here not that it is going to do any good because the code that breaks is the second call to the frozen column.

```
    Dim DT as New DataTable
    Dim DT2 as New DataTable

    DT = object.getDataTable 'this is where the sql is being pulled from

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = DT

    DT2 = object.getDataTable 'this is where the sql is being pulled from

    Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = DT2


    'Frozen function
     IF Me.DataGridView1.RowCount > 0 Then
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns("ThisColumn").Frozen = True
     End If

     IF Me.DataGridView2.RowCount > 0 Then
        Me.DataGridView2.Columns("ThisColumn").Frozen = True
     End If
```

that's it, there are other functions but they don't break it I have commented all of them out and the only one that breaks it is the Frozen function as defined above.

Comment: A bit of code might help us to understand the exact problem much easily.

Comment: Um ok so the only code would be the freeze Me.DataGridView.Columns("thiscolumn").Frozen = true. That is the same for both grids except it has a different name for the second one

Comment: See... instead of making us write the whole code (i.e., create a new project, add a TabControl, put two DataGridView, etc.) and intend to guess what you did (by assuming that you didn't add something wrong). Why don't you post your code (or a representable sample) to speed up the process and the understanding of the exact problem? Also this is one of the minimum requirements to ask questions here (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Lastly, note that there is some kind of bug involving these two controls (you can find lots of matches in any search engine) and thus the more info the better.

Comment: From this code is impossible to extract any information. You should explain what is everything (or include whole code + inputs). Also bear in mind that the bug I referred does not provoke crashes (not as far as I know), just slight "styling problems" (while changing colors and things like that). If you want help you would have to allow helpers to reproduce your exact conditions.

Comment: I don't know what else to give you that is basically what I have. the other things I mentioned don't do anything that would cause the error I'm getting. I have had someone who is more versed in this than I check it and he couldn't see why it would cause the issue.

Comment: For example `"ThisColumn"` does not mean anything `object.getDataTable` is not clearly either (= has the DataGridView values at all)? It is not clear either what is the basic configuration of the DGV; that is: this is not what I call an easily reproduceable code. But well... you are right: I haven't ever heard about such an error and cannot replicate your exact conditions; thus better wait for someone who has heard about it.

Comment: the name of the column doesn't really matter. Suffice it to say that "this column" refers to the same column in both gridviews. And the object is an object that we have created to hold the datatables.

Comment: These were just examples to show that the code wasn't easily reproduceable (= lots of things can fit there). Also you are talking about a TabControl which does not appear anywhere... Reproduceable conditions mean that anyone should be able to take your code and get the same results than you do (if your code is too big or you cannot post some parts; you should make a further effort to create a clear version to post here). With this question/code, the only chance you have of getting help is that your problem is more or less generic and familiar to someone. Not my case; so... please, wait.

Comment: I fixed it. Apparently you can't hide a column before you freeze a different one. Which doesn't make sense but sure.

Comment: "Apparently you can't hide a column before you freeze a different one" -> can you please explain me the exact part of the posted code where you are hiding a column?